# What are some other search functions for knockout.js besides stringStartsWith?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently doing a search function for knockout application. Currently, I have these lines of code which filters out products by the first letters in the product name. Is there a way to make it so that it searches for the whole array for matching String instead of `stringStartsWith`?

```
self.searchrice = ko.computed(function () {
    if (!self.searchString()) {
        return self.rice(); 
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.rice(), function (product) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(product.name.toUpperCase(), self.searchString().toUpperCase());
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So, you want to create a search function that only returns results that match exactly? So `Test` will *no longer* be matched to `T`, `Te` or `Tes`?

Comment: Bear in mind that `stringStartsWith` is only there because it's (presumably) used internally by knockout.  Everything else is still just JavaScript, so don't restrict your search for string manipulation stuff to knockout supplied functionality - you've got the whole remit of JavaScript available to you.

Comment: Did you not write this code? Because if you wrote this code yourself you would understand it well enough to answer your own question. If you did not write this code yourself, you really should take the time to understand it first, instead of asking people to make changes to it that you again won't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.searchrice = ko.computed(function () {
    if (!self.searchString()) {
        return self.rice(); 
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.rice(), function (product) {
               return (product.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(self.searchString().toUpperCase()) != -1);
        });
    }
});
```